# Generate file with node IDs which have edges between them in Python

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have two csv files: nyc_taxi_data.csv and nodes.csv. I am trying to output edges.csv that will have node IDs of long/lats that are in both files.

nyc_taxi_data.csv looks like this:

```
pickup_lat,pickup_long,dropoff_lat,dropoff_long.,trip_distance

72.1,43.4,72.3,43.6,0.8

**72.1,41.2,72.1,42.6,1.5**

**73.6,43.4,72.3,43.6,1.2**
```

nodes.csv looks like this:

```
node_id,lat,long

0,72.1,43.4

1,72.1,41.2

**2,73.6,43.4**

**3,72.3,43.6**

4,72.1,42.6
```

If for a pair of node ids 1 & 2, there is a trip in the nyc_taxi_data.csv, then this should be represented as 2 edges in the edges.csv file. One from node 1 to node 2 and another from node 2 to node 1.

Below is an example of how the output for edges.csv should look. Look at how the bolded values in nyc_taxi_data.csv & nodes.csv are used for the edges.csv file.

edges.csv:

```
node_id1,node_id2

0,3

3,0

2,4

4,2

*2,3*

*3,2*
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this is to break down the solution into 3 steps:

1. Create translation table (I name it lookup) to translate from (lat, long) to node ID
2. Read `nyc_taxi_data.csv` and translate
3. Store into edges.csv

```py
import csv
from pprint import pprint

# Step 1
lookup = {}
with open("nodes.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as stream:
    reader = csv.DictReader(stream)
    for row in reader:
        lookup[(row["lat"], row["long"])] = row["node_id"]
pprint(lookup)
```

Output:

```py
{('72.1', '41.2'): '1',
 ('72.1', '42.6'): '4',
 ('72.1', '43.4'): '0',
 ('72.3', '43.6'): '3',
 ('73.6', '43.4'): '2'}
```

```py
# Step 2
edges = []
with open("nyc_taxi_data.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as stream:
    reader = csv.DictReader(stream)
    for row in reader:
        node_id1 = lookup[(row["pickup_lat"], row["pickup_long"])]
        node_id2 = lookup[(row["dropoff_lat"], row["dropoff_long"])]
        edges.append((node_id1, node_id2))
        edges.append((node_id2, node_id1))
pprint(edges)
```

Output:

```py
[('0', '3'), ('3', '0'), ('1', '4'), ('4', '1'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '2')]
```

```py
# Step 3
with open("edges.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as stream:
    writer = csv.writer(stream)
    writer.writerow(("node_id1", "node_id2"))
    writer.writerows(edges)
```

Once we are happy with each output, we can remove the `pprint` calls.